# How to post Javascript array to C# list of tuples ?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, arrays, asp.net-mvc

I was wondering if anyone knew how to pass a Javascript array of objects to a MVC action method accepting an array of tuples.

Example:

The Javascript:

```
var objectArray = 
[
    { id: 1, value: "one" },
    { id: 2, value: "two" }
];

$.post('test',objectArray);
```

The MVC controller action:

```
public JsonResult Test((int id, string value)[] objectArray)
{
    return Json(objectArray != null);
}
```

Unfortunately the example I've given always returns false as the objectArray in the C# code is null.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a proper class?  This isn't really what Tuples were designed for.

Comment: @freedomn-m No reason, just curiosity.

Comment: @freedomn-m, yes, tuples aren't designed for this. Also, model binding cannot map to one `Tuple`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do this because like the **error** says: a tuple has no [parameterless constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150(v=vs.110).aspx), so the model binder can't instantiate it.

Also, you can read more about [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding).

One of the phrases said this:

> In order for binding to happen the class must have a public default
>   constructor and member to be bound must be public writable properties.
>   When model binding happens the class will only be instantiated using
>   the public default constructor, then the properties can be set.

You can use another approach:

First of all, you have to send the given **array** using `JSON.stringify` method.

`JSON.stringify()` turns a **javascript** object to `json` text and stores it in a `string`.

AJAX

```
objectArray = JSON.stringify({ 'objectArray': objectArray });
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'test',
    data: objectArray ,
    success: function () {          

    }
});
```

In your server-side method you have to pass a list of objects as parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public void PassThings(List<Thing> objectArray )
{

}

public class Thing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a way of doing it but it doesn't answer my question. I'm specifically trying to see if it's possible to receive an array of Tuples.

Comment: @RianMostert, then try this: `public void PassThings(List<Tuple<int, string>> objectArray )`

Comment: Afraid that didn't work. "No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'System.Tuple'..."

Comment: When do you receive this type of error ? compile time or runtime ?

Comment: I receive this error during runtime and if I use what I originally did "(int id, string value)[] objectArray" with the Json.Stringify then all the values are their defaults, aka, two [0,""] tuples.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Yes, because cannot call the constructor and also do not have getters and setters.

Comment: That's unfortunate but probably for the best, thank you!

Comment: @RianMostert, You're welcome ! I also add a quote from `Model binding` article.

Comment: Can we write our own custom model binder to overcome this issue ?

Comment: Yes, good point! You must try this. Have a look here how to create custom model binder https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1021934/Model-Binder-Basics-and-Custom-Model-Binder